# How do I lock the trackpad on the Lenovo x250

Tags: touchpad, lenovo-laptop, lock

How do I lock the trackpad on the Lenovo x250? I find no shortkey on the keyboard to do this. Is it possible to lock it temporarily without disable it in BIOS or the mouse properties?

UPDATE: I don't see any symbol on any key that seems to be related to turn off the trackpad. The fn + f6 or fn + f8 don't work for my lenovo model x250.

It seems really stupid if you aren't able to turn off the trackpad. Can that really be the case with the Lenovo x250? On my Lenovo g510 I can turn off the trackpad by just clicking on the f6 button. Any ideas?

Comment: Try FN+F6 to enable/disable the touchpad. Also check this link out. . . [http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/videos/ht051314

Comment: You should be able to disable it in your operating system.

Comment: AFH: my question:"Is it possible to lock it temporarily without disable it in BIOS or the mouse properties?", So what do you mean with "You should be able to disable it in your operating system".